# underscore each method not returning value

Tags: underscore.js

Not sure why this would not work. Shouldn't the index be returned and the loop stop.
I only need to return the index of the first value that is true and then not return any others

```js
var index = _.each([false, true, true],function(flag, index){
    if(flag){ return index }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

`_.each` calls the iterator function for every element in the array, no matter what you return. I think `_.indexOf` is what you are looking for.

```
var index = _.indexOf([false, true, true], true);
```

Answer (score 2):

`_.each` is just an iterator and won't return the index. To use it to find an index as you're trying to do, you would want to do something like:

```
var trueIndex = -1;

_.each([false, true, true],function(flag, index){
  if (trueIndex < 0 && flag) { 
    trueIndex = index;
  }
});

if (trueIndex != -1) {
  alert(trueIndex);
}
```

It's probably easier to just use a while loop, though:

```
var flags = [false, true, true]
var f, index = 0;

while(f = flags[index++]) {
  if (f) break;    
}

alert (index);
```

Comment: and @Michael's indexOf solution is probably better than either. It's been around a while outside of underscore, too See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Answer (score 0):

indexOf return only one value which is what you need :)
However... you can use map with filter if you need all of them :D Maybe there is an easier solution...

```
_(_.map([false, true, true], function(obj, index){ if(obj)return index; })).filter(function(num, index){return num != undefined});
```

this returns an array: [1,2]